# Why it seems that I have all my commit in the same branch also if I created a new one and commit into this new branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-log

I am very new in **GIT** and I have the following doubt with branches.

I have used the following command to create a new branch named **easy-mode**:

```
git branch easy-mode
```

Then I see al my branches and this is the output:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids (easy-mod
e)
$ git branch
* easy-mode
  master
```

So it should means that the **easy-mode** branch was correctly created and that in this moment it is the active branch. Is it true?

Ok, then I have modified a file named **game.js**, I have added it to the staging area and finally I have committed it. So I expect that this commit is related to the **easy-mode** branch that is the active branch.

The problem now is that trying to show the commit graph I obtain these result:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids (easy-mod
e)
$ git log --graph master easy-mode
* commit 59b4bce5964825b7c6fec4270ba34d2166f5168e
| Author: Andrea Nobili <nobili.andrea@gmail.com>
| Date:   Thu Jul 28 13:17:01 2016 +0200
|
|     Make asteroids split into 2 smaller pieces instead of 3
|
* commit cba1887f66a579e81c70a607d8402e84fa6e966d
| Author: Andrea Nobili <nobili.andrea@gmail.com>
| Date:   Thu Jul 28 12:30:06 2016 +0200
|
|     fixing: fixed the bug related of the weapon delay
|
* commit 3884eab839af1e82c44267484cf2945a766081f3
| Author: cbuckey <caroline@udacity.com>
| Date:   Fri Apr 29 12:33:05 2011 -0700
|
|     Add color
|
* commit 3e42136a76cf78c6c421cd720427bf6337c2d623
| Author: Doug McInnes <doug@dougmcinnes.com>
| Date:   Tue Mar 15 22:34:49 2011 -0700
|
|     now using requestAnimationFrame
|
|     see this for more info:
|     http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
|
* commit 4035769377cce96a88d5c1167079e12f30492391
| Author: Doug McInnes <doug@dougmcinnes.com>
| Date:   Wed Jun 9 21:04:32 2010 -0700
:
```

So I am performing the command:

```
git log --graph master easy-mode
```

and I expect to see the **master** branch that is branched into the **easy-mode** branch containing the last commit (**commit 59b4bce5964825b7c6fec4270ba34d2166f5168e**) into the **easy-mode** branch.

But it seems to me that I have no **easy-mode** branch and that all the commits are on the same line.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**

This is the output of the **git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all** command:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids (easy-mod
e)
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* 67e5e37 (HEAD -> easy-mode) feature: easy mode, the asteroids are split in 2 instead of 3
* cba1887 (master) fixing: fixed the bug related of the weapon delay
* 3884eab (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add color
* 3e42136 now using requestAnimationFrame
* 4035769 frame interval was set wrong after game was paused
* 25ede83 a couple missing ends with the ipad version
* df03538 I can't spell 'screen' apparently :)
| * 354dfdd (origin/coins) Make ships able to spawn on coins
| * 0c6daf1 Make it possible to collect coins
| * a3c0ae4 Create helper functions
| * 656b02e First pass at adding coins
|/
* b0678b1 Revert controls
* f19cb1b Fix typo in space
* 75928a9 Use space for movement and enter for shooting
* ac83b72 mostly finished ipad version
```

As you can see the last commit is:

```
* 67e5e37 (HEAD -> easy-mode) feature: easy mode, the asteroids are split in 2 instead of 3
```

I can't understand if it is into the new **easy-mode** branch or if it is into the **master** branch because in the printed graph I can't see the **|/** that identify the new branch into the graph (as the **coins** branch showed into the previous output).

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You could add `--decorate=full` to see which commit each branch is pointing to. Commits are connected in the way how the graphic describes. The so-called branches are just labels that refer to a commit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create *and checkout* the new branch in one command

```
git checkout -b easy-mode
```

The most common command to see all your branches neatly labeled with just the one line commit message

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

I usually assign these long common commands an alias

```
git config --global alias.la 'log --graph --oneline --decorate --all'
```

Now you'll be able to call it simply with

```
git la
```

Comment: mmm I have add some further information at the end of my original post. I tryed your solution but I can't understand if I have a new branch or not. Or how read the graph

Comment: You can confirm your current state with `git status`

Answer (score 0):

**easy-mode** branch appears as a continuation of the **master** branch because nothing was committed into **master** since **easy-mode** was created:

```
    master                                   master
      |                                        |
      v            is topologically            v
A--B--C             equivalent to        A--B--C--D
       \                                          ^
        D                                         |
        ^                                     easy-mode
        |
    easy-mode
```

Create an experimental clone of your repository and commit something into **master**. Then your history will no longer be linear, and **easy-mode** will be explicitly distinct from **master**:

```
       master
         |
         v
A--B--C--E
       \
        D
        ^
        |
    easy-mode
```